# SqlDataReader how to bind Inner join data to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

Currently I'm trying to combine two database tabels with a join
[image]

After that I looping through the reader and create an Appointment Object foreach row that returned from the query. That Appointment object is added to a list.

[image]

The problem is when I start my program. The user data is not binded to the Customer object.
Customer is still null here, but the customer data is added with the join.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? So that the Customer data that comes from the join is added to that Customer Model object.

Comment: Soo.. where's the bit of your code that looks like `appointments.Add(new Appointment { ... Customer = new Customer( CustomerId = int.Parse( reader["CustomerId"]))` ?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, paste them in as text. Please use images ony for things that cannot be shown as text

Comment: Side point: you need `using` blocks for your connection, command and reader objects

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshots, I can't see explicit binding for cutomer-related fields. And to understand the logic well, the list of appointments should have some sort of Customer object that u need to initialize while looping the reader.

```
appointments.add(new Appointment{
  Customer = new Customer{
    customerId = reader["Customers.CustomerId"]
    .
    .
    .
  },
  AppointmentId = reader["AppointmentId"],
  .
  .
  .
}
```